# For those of us whose career predates the web

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Can we have a place where those of us who published papers before the web existed can talk about them? Some of my presentations can't be identified by just a URL. (That seems to include JavaOne, which doesn't maintain a URL for each paper presented)